# Unit tests testing thread safety - Object not available randomly

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, thread-safety

We have some legacy code that tests thread safety on a number of classes. A recent hardware upgrade (from 2 to 4 core) is presenting random failures with an exception accessing an item from  List<>.

```
        [Test]
        public void CheckThreadSafeInThreadPool()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initialised ThreadLocalDataContextStore...");
            var container = new ContextContainerTest();
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
            container.StartPool();
            while (container.ThreadNumber < 5)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            foreach (var message in container.Messages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                if (message.Contains("A supposedly new thread is able to see the old value"))
                {
                    Assert.Fail("Thread leaked values - not thread safe");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Complete");

        }




public class ContextContainerTest
    {
        private ThreadLocalDataContextStore store;
        public int ThreadNumber;
        public List<string> Messages;

        public void StartPool()
        {
            Messages = new List<string>();

            store = new ThreadLocalDataContextStore();
            store.ClearContext();
            var msoContext = new MsoContext();
            msoContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("0"), null);
            store.StoreContext(msoContext);

            for (var counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
            {
                Messages.Add(string.Format("Assigning work item {0}", counter));
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ExecuteMe, counter);
            }
        }

        public void ExecuteMe(object input)
        {

            string hashCode = Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode().ToString();

            if (store.GetContext() == null || store.GetContext().Principal == null)
            {
                Messages.Add(string.Format("[{0}] A New Thread", hashCode));
                var msoContext = new MsoContext();
                msoContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("2"), null);
                store.StoreContext(msoContext);
            }
            else if (store.GetContext().Principal.Identity.Name == "1")
            {
                Messages.Add(string.Format("[{0}] Thread reused", hashCode));
            }
            else
            {
                Messages.Add(string.Format("[{0}] A supposedly new thread is able to see the old value {1}"
                    , hashCode, store.GetContext().GetDiagnosticInformation()));
            }

            Messages.Add(string.Format("[{0}] Context at starting: {1}", hashCode, store.GetContext().GetDiagnosticInformation()));
            store.GetContext().SetAsCurrent(new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("99"), null));
            Messages.Add(string.Format("[{0}] Context at End: {1}", hashCode, store.GetContext().GetDiagnosticInformation()));
            store.GetContext().SetAsCurrent(new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("1"), null));

            Thread.Sleep(80);
            ThreadNumber++;
        }


    }
```

The failure is random, and occurs at the following section of code within the test itself;

```
        foreach (var message in container.Messages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            if (message.Contains("A supposedly new thread is able to see the old value"))
            {
                Assert.Fail("Thread leaked values - not thread safe");
            }
        }
```

A subtle change resolves the issue, but someone is niggling that we should not need to do that, why is the message null if Messages is not and why does it work most of the time and not others.

```
 if (message != null && message.Contains("A supposedly new thread is able to see the old value"))
{
}
```

Another solution was to change the List to be threadsafe, but that doesnt answer why the issue arose in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't look like a unit test - it's not simple, not clear, doesn't seem to test only one thing and has complex setup logic. Convert your list to a threadsafe class or use locks when you access the list - it's likely to be a race condition of some sort. You had spent a lot more time typing this question than just changing the code to use correct data structures in a multithreaded environment. Alternatively, just delete this test - it smells bad.

Comment: "Another solution was to change the List to be threadsafe, but that doesnt answer why the issue arose in the first place" - but issue is because List is not thread safe, what other reason you need?

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is not a thread safe element if you are using .Net 4 and above you can use `ConcurrentBag<T>` from `System.Collection.Concurrent` and if older you got to implement one yourself. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx/) might help.

Hope I was helpful.